# Was Walden Macnair made Executioner again in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Macnair served as Executioner in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* because he was the one sent to kill Buckbeak. We also know he was arrested at the end of*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* because he served as a Death Eater.

But the [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Executioner) says:

> the takeover of the Ministry in the later year may have regained his position.

So did he become Executioner again in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*?

Answer (score 4):

If this happened it is not mentioned in the books. Following the battle in the Department of Mysteries at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*, Macnair is almost a non-character. He is not mentioned at all in *Half-Blood Prince*, and he only appears once in *Deathly Hallows* when he is knocked out by Hagrid during the battle at Hogwarts.

We do know from Hagrid that Macnair particularly enjoys killing, so perhaps it would not be surprising if he had specifically asked to be reinstated as executioner, but there doesn't seem to be any evidence in the books that this actually happened. This is what Hagrid said when he returned from his expedition to the giants in *Order of the Phoenix*:

> “Because I recognized one of ’em,” Hagrid growled.  “Macnair, remember
>   him? Bloke they sent ter kill  Buckbeak? Maniac, he is. Likes killin’
>   as much as  Golgomath, no wonder they were gettin’ on so well.”

Voldemort did promise Macnair better victims when the Death Eaters convened at the end of *Goblet of Fire*, but that doesn't necessarily tell us whether he would have wanted or not wanted Macnair to also be the Ministry executioner:

> “Macnair ... destroying dangerous beasts for the  Ministry of Magic
>   now, Wormtail tells me? You shall  have better victims than that soon,
>   Macnair. Lord  Voldemort will provide. ...”

Answer (score 1):

We don't know for certain, but probably not.

I don't have the books right now, but I remember voldy saying something like

> "working as Executioner for the Ministry now?! Lord Voldemort will
>   supply better prey..."

(GoF, at Voldemort's re-birth party)